# proxmox summary graphs not refreshing

Tags: proxmox

In the proxmox summary page, the graphics are not refreshing. Or they are, but no info is displayed.

Also, the containers status is wrong.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: i've already restarted pvedeamon with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it was as simple as doing this:

```
service pvestatd start
```

No upgrade, no machine restart.

Answer (score 0):

You must update and upgrade your proxmox version from repository or install new versions. I solved the above with proxmox 2.1

I hope help you.

Comment: Thanks! I was (will) try this but I need to backup everything and it's going to take a wile. No problems with the upgrade?

Comment: Yes, if you upgrade your version of proxmox of the repository not will lose any data.

I recommend that you upgrade.

Comment: Do you upgraded?

Comment: not yet. I will feedback when I do.

Comment: I didn't upgrade and I solved it. Check the answer above. Thanks anyway!